# Stiefel Whitney classes on the simplex or the simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, group-cohomology, characteristic-classes

The Stiefel Whitney classes of the base manifold $M$ are characteristic class as
$$
w_j(M) \in H^j(M,\mathbb{Z}_2),
$$

> - Puzzle: How do we write
>     $$
>   w_1(M) \in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)
>   $$
>     $$
>   w_2(M) \in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)
>   $$
>     on the simplex or the simplicial complex of base manifold?

For example, how is it be different from the $G$-group cohomology cocycle on the base manifold $M$, say
$$
\omega_1(G) \in H^1(G,\mathbb{Z}_2)
$$
$$
\omega_2(G) \in H^1(G,\mathbb{Z}_2),
$$
if I can pair the $\omega_j(G)$ to the base manifold $M$ through the fundamental classes?

Comment: maybe related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096233/why-are-stiefel-whitney-classes-not-represented-in-de-rham-cohomology

Comment: also I find this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788192/geometric-picture-of-stiefel-whitney-class-of-a-tangent-bundle?rq=1